# C++ Packet Builder with Templates

Tags: c++, linker-errors, packet, memcpy

PacketBuilder is a little Class which allow to write into a char* array. The Append Functions:

```
template <class T>
void PacketBuilder::Append(const T value)
{
 memcpy((&m_Buffer) + m_Index, (const void*) &value, sizeof(T));
 m_Index += sizeof(T);
}
```

Compiling without errors. If I call Append and use T as unsigned short (WORD). It works great. If I use T as unsigned char. I get an Linker Error.

```
m_Builder.Append<unsigned char>(0x01); // Error: LNK1120
m_Builder.Append<unsigned short>(0x0001); // Works
```

Error from VS2010 (sry i got german vs2010):

> error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht
>   aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public:
>   void __thiscall
>   PacketBuilder::Append(unsigned char)"
>   (??$Append@E@PacketBuilder@@QAEXE@Z)"
>   in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall
>   Client::DoHandshake(void)"
>   (?DoHandshake@Client@@QAEXXZ)".
>   1>C:\XXX\C++\SilkroadEmu\Debug\LoginServer.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht
>   aufgelöste externe Verweise.

Translated to English:

> error LNK2019: Unresolved external
>   symbol ""public: void __thiscall
>   PacketBuilder::Append(unsigned char)"
>   (??$Append@E@PacketBuilder@@QAEXE@Z)"
>   in Function ""public: void __thiscall
>   Client::DoHandshake(void)"
>   (?DoHandshake@Client@@QAEXXZ)".
>   1>C:\XXX\C++\SilkroadEmu\Debug\LoginServer.exe
>   : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unsresolved
>   external symbol.

Comment: Can you add the actual linker error messages to your question?

Comment: `LNK1120` only tells you the number of unresolved externals. You need to post the entire linker error message, including all the `LNK2001` messages that come before the `LNK1120` message. Just telling us the error code is not enough, as there are many, many causes of a `LNK2001` error. If those error messages refer to code that's not part of your question, you should add a minimal code snippet of those as well.

Comment: I can only guess what the problem is given the current information, but perhaps these will be of help: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12 and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PacketBuilder` is not a class template, as far as I can see. `PacketBuilder::Append` is however a template method, which requires that it's definition must be visible at any point of instantiation of this method. The only really safe way to assure this is to put the complete definition of this method template into the header file:

```
class PacketBuilder {
 // declarations of non-template members

public:
 template <class T> 
 void Append(const T value) 
 { 
  memcpy((&m_Buffer) + m_Index, (const void*) &value, sizeof(T)); 
  m_Index += sizeof(T); 
 }

};
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the method definition in the header (hpp file), not in the implementation (cpp) file.

Comment: Already done this: template <class T>void Append(const T value);

Comment: @Aurus: The definition includes the entire function body, as in the code between the braces (`{ ... }`). What you have is just the function *declaration*. You need to include the entire function definition in the header file.